# Is it true that $\partial\partial E=\partial E$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $E\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be an arbitrary subset. Is it true that
$$
\partial\partial E=\partial E
$$
The inclusion $\partial\partial E\subset \partial E$ is pretty clear to me since $\partial E$ is closed, however I fail to see the other inclusion. How to prove it?

Comment: What about the rationals in the reals?

Answer (score 9):

It's False:

Consider $\mathbb Q\subset \mathbb R$ then $\partial \mathbb Q=\mathbb R$ but $\partial\partial \mathbb Q=\emptyset$ .

However you cold prove that $\partial \partial \partial A= \partial\partial A$ for any set A.

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_(topology)#Boundary_of_a_boundary) says:

> $\partial\partial E=\partial E$
>   iff  $\partial E$ has no interior points